# Drupal Views exposed filter of Author name

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I have a view which I would like to add an exposed filter of the author name. So I can filter all the posts created by "John Smith" etc. I can't seem to see it listed under filter. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under `Build > Views` (`/admin/build/views`)

- add a filter (from filter category `user`)
- click `Expose` in the filter configuration section (near to the right border).

Comment: The problem is author name does not seem to be there

Comment: Create a filter, take category "User" and choose an appropriate field.

Comment: Do you know hot make this a drop down rather then enter the username?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881718/drupal-views-exposed-filter-of-author-name-as-a-drop-down

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a little harder than it sounds. You need to create a "Relationship" to the "Node revision: User", and then under the filter section, choose the User category and pick User:uid, and choose "Use relationship..."

Answer (score 0):

For applying filter using views you can follow the following steps:-

=> Go to administer setting 
=> site building 
=> views 
=> add view 
=> edit the view name and its description also the tag 
=> add a filter in right side 
=> then select on which type of node or 
whatever you choose and then apply the filter.

suppose if you choose the filter on node then you can select what condition either it is published, type, etc and after doing this you can choose your node type from option(is one of).
now you can apply filter on your desired type or node.