# Drupal Views exposed filter of Author name as a drop down

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

This is a follow up question to [Drupal Views exposed filter of Author name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880679/drupal-views-exposed-filter-of-author-name). The following question was answered and works. I can filter a view by user name. The user name is entered is entered by typing in a box and the box then auto completes. Rather then doing this I would like the list of users as a drop down. I only need one user to be selected. Do you know if this is possible?

Answer (score 25):

You'll need a custom module for that.

I've done this for Drupal 7 this way: create a module, say, `views_more_filters`, so you have a `views_more_filters.info` file like this:

```
name = Views More Filters
description = Additional filters for Views.
core = 7.x

files[] = views_more_filters_handler_filter_author_select.inc
files[] = views_more_filters.views.inc
```

(file `views_more_filters_handler_filter_author_select.inc` will contain our filter handler).

A basic `views_more_filters.module` file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements of hook_views_api().
 */
function views_more_filters_views_api() {
  return array('api' => 3);
}
```

Then define your filter in `views_more_filters.views.inc`:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements of hook_views_data().
 */
function views_more_filters_views_data() {
  return array(
    'node' => array(
      'author_select' => array(
        'group' => t('Content'),
        'title' => t('Author UID (select list)'),
        'help' => t('Filter by author, choosing from dropdown list.'),
        'filter' => array('handler' => 'views_more_filters_handler_filter_author_select'),
        'real field' => 'uid',
      )
    )
  );
}
```

Note that we set `author_select` as a machine name of the filter, defined filter handler (`'handler' => 'views_more_filters_handler_filter_author_select'`) and a field we will filter by (`'real field' => 'uid'`).

Now we need to implement our filter handler. As our filter functions just like default `views_handler_filter_in_operator`, we simply extend its class in `views_more_filters_handler_filter_author_select.inc` file:

```
<?php
/**
 * My custom filter handler
 */
class views_more_filters_handler_filter_author_select extends views_handler_filter_in_operator {

  /**
   * Override parent get_value_options() function.
   *
   * @return
   *   Return the stored values in $this->value_options if someone expects it.
   */
  function get_value_options() {
    $users_list = entity_load('user');

    foreach ($users_list as $user) {
      $users[$user->uid] = $user->name;
    }

    // We don't need Guest user here, so remove it.
    unset($users[0]);

    // Sort by username.
    natsort($users);

    $this->value_options = $users;

    return $users;
  }
}
```

We haven't had to do much here: just populate options array with a list of our users, the rest is handled by parent class.

For further info see:

- [Views API](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/classes/7)
- [Where can I learn about how to create a custom exposed filter for Views 3 and D7?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26376/where-can-i-learn-about-how-to-create-a-custom-exposed-filter-for-views-3-and-d7) on Drupal Answers
- [Demystifying Views API - A developer's guide to integrating with Views](http://www.grasmash.com/article/demystifying-views-api-developers-guide-integrating-views)
- [Sophisticated Views filters, part2 - writing custom filter handler (in Russian, link to Google translator)](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=ru&tl=en&u=http://xandeadx.ru/blog/drupal/403)
- [Tutorial: Creating Custom Filters in Views](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/drupal-7-tutorial-creating-custom-filters-views)

Comment: This is the first solution I've found to this problem which is clean and makes sense. :)

Comment: Great solution, just one question here though. Should this change all the User filters (including the existing ones also) to dropdown?

Comment: Great answer. It is probably best to use `hook_views_data_alter` , since you are modifying an existing array.

Comment: If somebody wants to set default selection to current user it's as simple as adding few lines before `return $users;`
Here you go:
`global $user;
if (array_key_exists($user->uid, $users)) {
  $this->value = $user->uid;
}`

Answer (score 17):

Yes, this is possible. Its not particularly tough to do this... but its slightly tedious. You need to create two views

1. The first view is a list of users on your system (a View of type `Users`). This user list is displayed as a dropdown instead of a list (using jump menu view style). Clicking on any user within this dropdown will call the second view with the uid (user id) of the selected user as the argument in the URL. This view is a block.
2. The second view is a simple Node listing. It is a page view at a particular URL. It takes 1 argument which is the uid (user id) of the user.

Detailed Steps

1. Download the Ctools module
   http://drupal.org/project/ctools
   Enable the Chaos Tools Module. This
   module provides a Views Style Plugin
   called "Jump Menu"
2. Create a new view of type `Users` and NOT type `Node` which you usually
   create. In the fields add `User:
   Name` and `User: uid`. For the
   settings of `User: uid`, make sure
   you click on `Rewrite the output of
   the field`. The rewritten output of
   the field should be
   `my_node_list/[uid]`. Make sure you
   select the `exclude from display` checkbox.
3. In the settings for `Style` in the view, select the `Jump Menu` style. Click on the settings for the style. Make sure the `Path` dropdown has `User: uid` choosen
4. Add a block display to the view. Name the block `User Drop Down`
5. Save the view
6. Add the block `User Drop Down` to any region in your theme e.g. Content Top (usually the best) or left sidebar. Make sure the block is only visible at the urls `my_node_list/*` and `my_node_list` by setting the block visibility settings
7. Now create another view of type `Node`. Add an argument field `User: uid`. Add the fields you are interested in e.g. `Node: title`, `User: Name` etc.
8. Add a page display. Let the page be at the url `my_node_list`
9. Save the view. Test the dropdown with its list of users on the system at `http://yoursitename/my_node_list`

Comment: @Linda: did the answer help you out?

Comment: I think this is irrelevant to the OP question. Jump menu is different thing from views filter. The first jumps to a page, the second filters the results.

Comment: @swan - you're right that a Ctools Jump menu is a different thing than a filter, but because there is no out-of-the-box way to do a drop-down Views filter on user name, this is a clever workaround.

Answer (score -2):

http://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters
Check this one

Comment: I don't think this will give a dropdown with a list of all users. So I don't think this will be useful.

Answer (score -3):

I think you just have to choose "Taxonomy:term The taxonomy term ID" instead of "name".

Comment: Taxonomy isn't the same thing as User - so that filter wouldn't do the trick for this question.  That's a good answer for a taxonomy filter though!

Answer (score -3):

Found a simple solution here. http://bryanbraun.com/2013/08/06/drupal-tutorials-exposed-filters-with-views