# Drupal 7 Views add list of authors as exposed filter

Tags: forms, drupal, view

I have a view with a number of exposed filters that I want to add an exposed filter for the author, so that the user can limit a list of nodes by the creator of the node (in addition to a number of other filters).

**What I've done so far:**

I've added an exposed filter of the author and set the operator to "contains any word" (so the usernames could just be a + separated list)

1. This is by default a text field, but I would like it to appear as a list of checkboxes (similar to taxonomy)
2. Using hook_form_alter I've added the following code to change it to a list of checkboxes (harcoded for now but I'll fix shortly)

   $form['name']['#type'] = "select";
   $form['name']['#size'] = "3";
   $form['name']['#multiple'] = TRUE;

   $form['name']['#options'] = array(
       'admin' => 'admin',
       'tyler' => 'tyler',
       'test' => 'test'
   );
   $form['name']['#theme'] = "select_as_checkboxes";

When this form is submitted it changes the url to &name[]=tyler&name[]=admin, what I would like to do is combine these with a foreach so that url would look like &name=tyler+admin, but I'm really not sure how exactly to achieve this in the API.

I tried adding a function to $form['#submit'], and changing the value of the field in there, but that still didn't change the output.

Any advice?

**Quick Edit**

For the time being I have switched this to use radios instead of checkboxes, which solves the issue that I was having.

To break down the issue I was having a bit further, the names of the checkboxes where getting set to name[]= instead of name= because of the multiple inputs. The name filter in Views does not know how to handle multiple values for the name field.

For now I will see if this flies with the client, but if anybody has an answer for the original question of adding checkboxes for all authors to an exposed filter that would be awesome!

Comment: Also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16517124/1072114) for a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Better Exposed Filters](http://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) module.

Comment: I am using the Better Exposed Filters module. Is there some specific way of adding this functionality with BEF that I'm missing?

Comment: Change the operator "contains any word" to "is one of"