# drupal views display needs multiple sort order for exposed filter

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I have a 4 quicktabbed views blocks on a page and rightnow. All blocks show lists that can be sorted by "Title" with an exposed filter and a sort order dropdown button for options "A-Z" and "Z-A". So the user can view the list either way. I need to add another exposed filter option for posted date. I see how to do that and it's now an option in the pulldown button that shows "Title" but I can't see how to add option for "most recent" and "oldest" either in the sort order dropdown button or anywhere. Can this be done in the views UI or is this going to involve some php coding? If php, where do I start, given I'm a php newbie?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've figured it out yet, I had to do something similar recently.
this answer helped me [[Drupal 7: Exposed filter on a post date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235224/drupal-7-exposed-filter-on-a-post-date][1]) just to set up a created date filter.

As for the newest/oldest sort, you add `Content: Post date` to your Sort criteria, the you could maybe check the `Advanced sort options` in `BEF Settings` for your view. There you can combine 'sort order with sort by' like the following current_value|replacement_value pair:

```
    Publication date Asc|Oldest
    Publication date Desc|Newest
```

Let me know if that was helpful in any way or if you need a more detailed answer