# Drupal 7 Views: Exposed year filter based on node post dates

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-exposed-filter

I wanted to show an exposed selectbox year-filter based on the post date of nodes in a newslist view and i'm stuck.

i already tried this solution: [Drupal 7: Exposed filter on a post date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235224/drupal-7-exposed-filter-on-a-post-date/15241061#15241061) but this configuration has a downside: i have to manually set the year ranges which should be shown in the selectbox. I don`t want to set a "-3 year" and "+3 year" range. i just wanted to show the years of nodes that really exist.

How can i get a list of year dates as an exposed filter based on the post date of articles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the only working solution i found was creating a custom filter and add it as a module. as explained in this answer: [Drupal 7: Exposed filter on a post date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235224/drupal-7-exposed-filter-on-a-post-date/21411736#21411736)